# Detecting if the browser has blocked a specific call

Tags: adblock

Related to the subject of adblockers : it's easy to find if someone has an adblocker, but I am interested in finding out if the browser is blocking some analytics call too (cf the easyprivacy list for instance, or ublock).

Is there a way to find out if a specific js call has a "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT /failed" status?

Thanks !

Comment: Technically speaking the easy thing is detecting whether certain requests fail - not whether someone uses an ad blocker. Therefore you can use the same techniques for non-ad requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Any idea of how to look at that, where to look at?
thanks !